# How to test for completeness of string.xml

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

Is there a tool that would allow me to check if me localized `string.xml` file is complete.
E.g. that `values-de/strings.xml`  or `values-jp/string.xml` contains all the entries that `values/strings.xml` contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) tool.

If you use Eclipse it is available from menu bar (right button on the screenshot).

[image]

Comment: thanks, @bancer, that did it... explicitly invoking lint through above button  (or menu Window > Run Android Lint...  rather hidden there I say)

Answer (score 5):

In ADT 20 you have a Lint marker which tells you if there are some Strings files that are incomplete. To see the Lint warnings you'll have to go to Window -> show View -> Other -> Android -> Lint warnings.

Comment: thanks, but it seems you have to explicitly run lint first from the toolbar or menu, I did have some lint markers, but not all... good help, though